# 'Action name not found' error appears on invoking Salesforce Screen Flow via API

Tags: salesforce

I have a screen Flow with

```
Flow API Name   Create_Customer_License
Type    Screen Flow
Default URL /flow/Create_Customer_License
```

I'm, trying to invoke the flow via API but got an error

Endpoint

```
/services/data/v52.0/actions/custom/flow/Create_Customer_License
```

Request body:

```
{ 
"inputs" : [ {
   "Id" : "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
   } ] 
}
```

Error:

```
[ {
  "actionName" : "Create_Customer_License",
  "errors" : [ {
    "statusCode" : "MISSING_RECORD",
    "message" : "Action name not found: Create_Customer_License",
    "fields" : [ ]
  } ],
  "isSuccess" : false,
  "outputValues" : null
} ]
```

Is it possible to invoke such type of Flows via API?
Or what could be a problem?